# $U(f,p)-L(f,p)< \varepsilon$v(A)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:A ⊂  \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ bounded, with $A$ a closed rectangle. so if there's a oscillation  $o(f,x)< \varepsilon, \varepsilon>0,  $ for all x that belongs to A.  How can I show there is a partition P of A so:  $U(f,p)-L(f,p)< \varepsilon$v(A) (with v(A) the volume of A )

Comment: I have some problems understanding this post, can anybody help me with a detail answer please?

Comment: What is the definition of the oscillation $\text{o}(f,x)$?